# The total probability of a minimum amount probability-varied choosers choosing one option over another.

Tags: probability, word-problem

OK, the title may seem a bit convoluted but here it goes. This is an simplified example of what I am trying to get at. I am really more interested in the method of figuring this out, and how it can be applied to other, similar, problems.

10 people are presented with a binary choice with Option A and Option B. Person 1 has a 25% chance of picking Option B, Person 2 has a 30% chance, and so on, incriminating 5% each person (for simplicity sake). What is the total probability, in percentage, that at least 3 of these people will pick Option B?

Comment: What sort of answer are you hoping for?  It's not especially difficult to compute the probability $0$ people choose $B$, nor that exactly $1$ person does.  More work to handle exactly $2$ people, but perfectly possible.  I don't imagine there's a simple closed formula.  With more complex probabilities, I'd simply sample the problem.

Comment: @lulu The parameters I am looking at are this:

A binary choice.
A group of _m_ people.
Each person has their own probability regarding their choice.

The answer is the probability of at least _n_ people, out of the _m_, choosing a specific option.

Comment: Right.  In that context, I would sample.  That should work quite well, unless you have a large block of low probability cases.  That sort of thing can be hard on sampling methods.  But that's probably not the situation you are worried about, yes?

Comment: I am unsure on what you mean by sampling. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure.  In your general context, choose a large number ($10^5$ or more) $m$-tuples of uniformly random numbers between $0$ and $1$.  Use those $m$-tuples to produce a trial vote.  Then count the cases in which whatever you wanted to happen happens.  Machines are very good at this sort of thing.

Comment: OK, that is the long way around though. I know how to solve this word problem it is was the chance of them all picking an option, it's simple multiplication. What if the answer was simplified to "What is the probability of exactly 3 people choosing the option?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48401/discussion-between-user3670473-and-lulu).

Comment: @user3670473 Quote:"What if the answer was simplified to "What is the probability of exactly 3 people choosing the option?" This is not really a simplification. Fewer amount of people would be more helpful.

Comment: I concur with @callculus ...adding "exactly" does not simplify the problem.  Nor do I consider sampling to be "the long way around".  To the contrary, a good sampling program should be robust...so that you can easily change the probabilities without rewriting the code.  Closed formulas may well be possible for particular choices of probabilities, but shifting those around is almost sure to break simple analytics.

Comment: Well personally, right now, I don't have time to build a robust sampling system.

Comment: Presumably, these probabilities are independent.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, they are independent. (Although hypothetically two or more people can have the same probability, each one can be anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A smaller example to show how the calculation works. Suppose that you have $4$ people. Then

$P(X\geq 3)=P(X=3)+P(X=4)$

$P(X=3)=0.25\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.35\cdot (1-0.4)$

$+0.25\cdot 0.3\cdot (1-0.35)\cdot 0.4$

$+0.25\cdot (1-0.3)\cdot 0.35\cdot 0.4$

$+(1-0.25)\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.35\cdot 0.4$

$P(X=4)=0.25\cdot 0.3\cdot 0.35\cdot 0.4$

Thus $P(X\geq 3)=10.175\%$

Comment: Thank you. I assumed as much. I was just wondering if there was a more simpler method, which I now realize there is not.

Comment: @user3670473 You´re welcome. Yes, I also think that it cannot be simplified such that it helps much for large n´s.

Answer (score 0):

An exact answer is going to be painful. Let $p_i$ be the probability that person $i$ chooses box B, and these probabilities are independent.

Let $Q=(1-p_1)\cdots(1-p_{10})$.

Then the probability that *at least* three of them pick $B$ is:

$$1-Q\left[1+\sum_{i=1}^{10} \frac{p_i}{1-p_i} + \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq 10}\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\frac{p_j}{1-p_j}\right]$$

In your case, $p_i=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i-1}{20}=\frac{4+i}{20}$, so 
$$\begin{align}
Q&=\frac{14!}{4!20^{10}}\\\frac{p_i}{1-p_i}&=\frac{4+i}{16-i}
\end{align}$$

That sum is almost certainly still going to be complicated to calculate.

This value is just subtacting the cases where exactly zero, one, or two of the people select $B$.

The number of people choosing exactly three is:

$$Q\left[\sum_{1\leq i<j<k\leq 10} \frac{p_i}{1-p_i}\frac{p_j}{1-p_j}\frac{p_k}{1-p_k}\right]$$

Again, ugly.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the response.